# Face Detection on Camera video input on iPhone

Tags: ios4, opencv, avfoundation

I am working on a project that needs to do face detection on a camera video input (like security camera).

I managed to open Video input via AVFoundation framework. I managed to capture a UIImage from the video input, then feed into opencv library to do face detection.

But the process of capturing requires at least 2 to 3 seconds.

Is there anyone who got some experience to share ?

Comment: I don't know much about opencv, but if its code is not optimized for ARM NEON yet, you might want to delve into that. In another data-heavy project I managed to get a speed gain of 10 times over regular (slightly optimized) C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work with the limitation if iOS 5, you can get this to work pretty well with the new `CIFaceDetector` baked into the OS. That should help address performance concerns and simplify the code if you're not worried about implementing your own version of face detection.

Apple has some sample code projects up on the developer forums [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html). There are some details on the kind of data available using their [face detection here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html) and some basic docs for the [detector here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).